# ParameterBindingException with TroubleshootingPack

Tags: powershell

If I try to run the following lines of code I get the following exception:

### Error

```
Get-TroubleshootingPack : Es wurde kein Positionsparameter gefunden, der das Argument "Invoke-TroubleshootingPack" akzeptiert.
In Zeile:4 Zeichen:16
+ $PrinterPack = Get-TroubleshootingPack @TroubleshootingPack Invoke-Troubleshooti ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-TroubleshootingPack], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Windows.Diagnosis.Commands.GetTroubleshootingPack
```

### Code

```
$TroubleshootingPack = @{
Path = "$env:windir\diagnostics\system\printer"
}
$PrinterPack = Get-TroubleshootingPack @TroubleshootingPack Invoke-TroubleshootingPack -Pack $PrinterPack
```

I do not understand the problem because my code looks for me like an modification of the code from the help:

```
get-troubleshootingpack -path C:\Windows\Diagnostics\System\Aero | invoke-troubleshootingpack
```

Comment: I do not understand the error message because it is not translated to English. But the code is missing the pipeline `|`.

Comment: Even with the pipeline it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to change the question or ask another one.

Comment: Btw: the code is from the Powershell Bible book. Is there a different behavior between the v2 and v3 Powershell? Maybe someone can the code in v2 Powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem was a missing line break

```
$TroubleshootingPack = @{
Path = "$env:windir\diagnostics\system\printer"
}
$PrinterPack = Get-TroubleshootingPack @TroubleshootingPack
Invoke-TroubleshootingPack -Pack $PrinterPack
```

The above code works now without any problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Get-TroubleshootingPack @TroubleshootingPack | Invoke-TroubleshootingPack
```

or this

```
$PrinterPack = Get-TroubleshootingPack @TroubleshootingPack
Invoke-TroubleshootingPack -Pack $PrinterPack
```